# Javascript to Jquery conversion for some changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I want to modify a javascript code but I don't know much about javascript. Can anybody please convert this code to jquery? any help appreciated

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByName('show-pass-btn');
var myInput = document.getElementsByName('show-pass-input');
myButton.forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.onclick = function () {
    'use strict';

    if (myInput[index].type == 'password') {
      myInput[index].setAttribute('type', 'text');
      element.firstChild.textContent = 'Hide';
      element.firstChild.className = "";

    } else {
      myInput[index].setAttribute('type', 'password');
      element.firstChild.textContent = 'Show';
      element.firstChild.className = "";
    }
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<input
  type="password"
  value="<?php echo $user_password; ?>"
  name="show-pass-input"
  class="form-control-plaintext readonly"
>

<button
  type="button"
  name="show-pass-btn"
  class="btn btn-link btn-xs"
>
  Show
</button>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a nested html of the button so no firstChild

jQuery

```js
$('[name=show-pass-btn]').on("click", function() { 
  const $password = $(this).closest(".commonContainer").find('[name=show-pass-input]');
  const isPassword = $password.is(":password");
  $password.attr('type', isPassword ? 'text' : 'password');
  $(this).text(isPassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="commonContainer">
  <input type="password" value="" name="show-pass-input" class="form-control-plaintext readonly">
  <button type="button" name="show-pass-btn" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Show</button> 
</div>

<div class="commonContainer">
  <input type="password" value="" name="show-pass-input" class="form-control-plaintext readonly">
  <button type="button" name="show-pass-btn" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Show</button> 
</div>
```

Vanilla,

```js
document.getElementById("fieldContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("[name=show-pass-btn]")) return // not a button
  const passwordField = tgt.closest('.commonContainer').querySelector("[name=show-pass-input]");
  const isPassword = passwordField.type === "password";
  passwordField.type = isPassword ? 'text' : 'password';
  tgt.textContent = isPassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
})
```

```html
<div id="fieldContainer">
  <div class="commonContainer">
    <input type="password" value="" name="show-pass-input" class="form-control-plaintext readonly">
    <button type="button" name="show-pass-btn" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Show</button>
  </div>

  <div class="commonContainer">
    <input type="password" value="" name="show-pass-input" class="form-control-plaintext readonly">
    <button type="button" name="show-pass-btn" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Show</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

IF you can guarantee the button is right next to the field, we can do this:

```js
$('[name=show-pass-btn]').on("click", function() {
  const $password = $(this).prev();
  const isPassword = $password.is(":password");
  $password.attr('type', isPassword ? 'text' : 'password');
  $(this).text(isPassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" value="" name="show-pass-input" class="form-control-plaintext readonly">
<button type="button" name="show-pass-btn" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Show</button>

<input type="password" value="" name="show-pass-input" class="form-control-plaintext readonly">
<button type="button" name="show-pass-btn" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Show</button>
```

Comment: I edit the question with HTML and one more thing my data is dynamic and I have multiple password fields

Comment: I updated with two sets of passwords in two containers. The Vanilla version needs a wrapper to delegate well